# Can a virtual function be overridden by a non-virtual function?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, virtual-functions

In this code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
public:
    virtual void method() override { }
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
public:
    void method() override { }
};
```

Is there any difference between `Derived1` and `Derived2`?

Comment: `Derived2::method2` is virtual.

Comment: if syntax allows it. (not checked) then `derived2->method()` will also be virtual (implicit though)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: So the virtual keyword is implied?

Comment: @Alex: [Compiles fine](http://ideone.com/8158F2) for me under gcc-4.7.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From section *10.3 Virtual functions* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337) point 2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly
>   from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and refqualifier
>   (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, **then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is
>   so declared)** and it overrides Base::vf.

So `Derived2::method` is also `virtual`, even though it is not explicitly declared as such.

Comment: Is it ever desirable to declare the member without the virtual keyword? Can GCC be made to spit out a warning when that happens?

Comment: @Eric: Some argue that marking the derived function virtual serves as documentation, others argue that it is unnecessary code bloat.  In practice it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: With C++11 one can use the override keyword to indicate that a function in a derived class is virtual.

Comment: @Eric, I agrree with what user1131467. Personally, I prefer it for documentation. As for compiler switches to issue warnings I am unsure.

Comment: Perfect answer. Probably the confusion of the op comes from the fact that in newer languages, such as Java and C#, it is possible to declare a method to stop being virtual.

Answer (score 4):

They are identical.

`virtual` is optional when actually overriding a function. It is mandatory only when marking a function in the base class.