# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol in derived class

Tags: c++

The error occurred when I called a constructor of a derived class in another project. I omitted some details in the code. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

-Base/derived classes and the test file are in two different projects. Base/derived classes can be compiled without problems.

-The Test project can be compiled successfully when comment the constructor line.

-Test.cpp plays well with other constructor in the DerivationFunction file.

```
// Test.cpp
#include "DerivationFunction.h"

Child con(123, 123);  // error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Child::Child(unsigned short,unsigned int)" (??Child@@QAE@GI@Z) referenced in function _main
```

The header file of base class and derived class:

```
// DerivationFunction.h
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void AppendEnums() = 0;
    static int CopyBuffer();
    uint16 GetFeatureID();

protected:
    uint16 baseValue;
    static int Copy();
};

// Child class
class Child : public Base
{
public:
    uint32 childValue;
    Child(uint16 featureID, uint32 value);
    void AppendEnums();
};
```

The source file:

```
// DerivationFunction.cpp
int Base::CopyBuffer()
{
    return 0;
}

uint16 Base::GetFeatureID()
{
    return baseValue;
}

int Base::Copy()
{
    return 0;
}

// Child class
Child::Child(uint16 featureID, uint32 value)
{
    baseValue = featureID;
    childValue = value;
}

void Child::AppendEnums()
{
}
```

Comment: @hmjd sorry it's a typo. I omitted some details like the parameters in purpose. It should have no problem with the parameters.

Comment: use virtual in child AppendEnums class defintion too (ie: virtual void AppendEnums() )

Comment: @user1654209, that is unnecessary (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317083/can-a-virtual-function-be-overriden-by-a-non-virtual-function/17317140#17317140)

Comment: @hmjd i know, just got used to it :)

Comment: Make sure nothing redefines uint16 and/or uint32 in one of the headers you include in the source file. Try using unsigned short and  unsigned int in you AppendEnums definition and implementation to check for such re-defines

Comment: @user1654209 the type has no problem because the header/source files can be compiled without problem.

Comment: that's irrelevant. link errors occurs at link time (after compile time) . Child.cpp could refer to correct int16/32 while main.cpp includes another header before including Child.h and make the linker looks for another implementation. My original advice was just an easy check for this kind of problems as primitive types cannot be redefined

Comment: @user1654209 you are right. But I want to use machine-independent types, while short/int are not. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If the check i suggested shows that int16/32 are redefined, you just need to locate the header that made such defines and reorder your includes to have Child.h upfront. Or try to include <stdint.h> in both your child class  header and source file to enforce proper base types defines.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that you haven't built and included the implementation file in with your main and hence the linker cannot find the code for the `Child` constructor. Look in the MSDN help for that particular error code and check all of the possibilities there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use these classes in another project then you either include the whole sources (headers and cpp files) and build them, or export them from a DLL project and import them in the other project(s).